# PHP string parse error with necessary semicolon after variable

Tags: php, string

In my PHP code I have a variable `$message` which includes the message to be sent to me which has post variables in it. It is supposed to have a semicolon at the end...but it gives me an error saying it is unexpected but I know I need it because it wont work without it. I am at a complete loss. Hopefully someone here can help me.

Error Message:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';'
```

PHP Code

```
if(!empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["address"]) && !empty($_POST["city"]) && !empty($_POST["phone"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["type"]))
{
$message = "Name:" . $_POST["name"] . 
"Address:" . $_POST["address"] . 
"City:" . $_POST["city"] . 
"State:" . $_POST["state"] . 
"Zip Code:" . $_POST["zip"] . 
"Phone:" . $_POST["phone"] . 
"Email:" . $_POST["email"] . 
"Current Roof Type:" . $_POST["type"] . 
"Roof Age:" . $_POST["age"] .
"Is it leaking?:" . $_POST["leak"] . 
"Does it have hail damage?:" . $_POST["hail"] . 
"Insurance:" . $_POST["insurance"] . 
"Additional Comments:" . $_POST["extra"] . 
;                                          <---------------####Unexpected semicolon
$to = "emailasdasdasdasd";
$subject = "Free Estimate";
$from = "Guarantee Roofing";
$headers = "From:" . $_POST["name"];
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the problem

```
 "Additional Comments:" . $_POST["extra"] . 
 ;
```

should be

```
  "Additional Comments:" . $_POST["extra"]   ;
```

Comment: Wow, just that small of a problem...thank you though!

Comment: @SpencerMay yours very welcome ....

Answer (score 5):

```
"Additional Comments:" . $_POST["extra"] .  
                                         ^
```

Unnecessary concatenation operator -----------------here.

PHP is expecting a string/variable next to the concatenation operator and finds semicolon, which is reported **unexpected**.

Answer (score 2):

```
"Additional Comments:" . $_POST["extra"] . 
                                         ^---- dangling concatenation
;
```

you're telling PHP to concatenate a couple strings, and then terminate the statement without providing the second string.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extra dot at the end of the string, if you delete the line breaks, you'd end up with

```
 ... . "Additional Comments:" . $_POST["extra"] . ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that extra `.` after the last line which is implying concatenation.

Remove the . after this line:

```
"Additional Comments:" . $_POST["extra"] .
```